# number entered via inputbox not linked to my formulas in column B

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Could you please help me with  my Code below,what I want that excel does is the following: when the user enter via the input box a number (in this case "12"), the formula in B1 replace "nb" by the number entered by the user…. Currently the formula does not work because the default character "nb" in my formula

[image: img1]

`=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1;FIND(nb;A1);LEN(A1));" ";REPT(" ";100));100))` is remaining the enter image description heresame "nb" in all my formulas in column B after executing my macro... I would like that this "nb" in all my formulas in column B is replaced automatically by the number entered by the user via inputbox. Here this is my code below as well as the image (via the link below) what I get in column B. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

```
Sub FLS()
Dim nb As Byte
nb = Application.InputBox("Please enter character:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 1)
xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Range("B1").Select 
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(RC[-1],FIND(nb,RC[-1]),LEN(RC[-1])),"" "",REPT("" "",100)),100))" 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B3370"), Type:=xlFillDefault Range("B1:B3370").Select 
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, Selection.Column).End(xlUp).Select 
Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not concatenating your input `nb`. As you can see your output formula contains `nb` and not its value. correct your code to -

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(RC[-1],FIND(" & nb & ",RC[-1]),LEN(RC[-1])),"" "",REPT("" "",100)),100))"
```